# WPF Image Overlay

Tags: wpf, image, xaml, masking

I have an `<Image />` used in a ControlTemplate to show a 24 bit PNG. Ontop of this, I'd like to apply a semi-transparent gray layer to make it appear half disabled. The problem I'm having is that if I just apply a gray layer, the transparent parts of the image just change to gray, instead of staying transparent and only applying to the coloured parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set the [Opacity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.opacity.aspx) of the `Image` instead.

Comment: The could have worked but it got me thinking and I ended uop changing the image URI to a greyed out image instead.